# Understanding the SD Card Specification

Tags: performance, sd-card

I am looking buy a 256GB microSDXC-III (or microSD with 624MB/s theoretical max) but I am not sure I understand the SD card specifications, ratings, and markings.

I have been searching for better guidance on this and I've arrived at the following questions I can't seem to answer and hope someone can help:

[image]
https://satechi.net/blogs/news/ultra-high-speed-uhs-sd-memory-cards-differences-between-uhs-i-vs-uhs-ii
￼
[image]
https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/

I understand difference between SDHC and SDXC

1) What is the actual marking for UHS-III? ("U3" or XC-III) and what is the difference?

2) Can read/write speeds be compared directly amongst all speed classes?

3) Does the XC-I correspond to “U” rating/marking, the XC-II correspond to “V#” rating marking - if so what would the rating/marking look like for XC-III?

4) Based on 2), what is the “fastest” SD card - the V90 of the Video Speed Class?

5) Is there an explanation for the discrepancy in write speeds of the two sources (pictures)?

6) Is there a microSD counterpart for all of these SD cards?

Comment: Re #2 & #4: video speed ratings are irrelevant when used in PC/laptop/tablet.  There are several ways of reading/writing SD cards, and the block methods (as used/required by computing devices) are unrelated to  and cannot attain the fast speeds of the streaming methods (as used by video devices).